# Populate or change the selection options in one field based on selected option in another field in the CP

Tags: field, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I'm looking to change a select fields options with the onChange event from another select fields chosen option. Obviously this can be done with js on the frontend as per [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/tie-two-select-fields-together-based-on-category-and-subcategory) but has anyone done this for the control panel? I imagine it will need to be done via a fieldType plugin, but wondered if anything already exists for this type of functionality before I attempt to build something.

Comment: Do you already have a plugin and fieldType where you want to do this, or do you mean "this one built-in selectField is connected to this other built-in selectField?

Comment: Could be either. If there is a way to connect select fields in craft already then great where can I find the documentation for it. If not then I would be looking at a plugin to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a custom fieldtype (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) with two selects. Makes sense to make it as one field if they are dependent of eachother.

Just store the field as json (AttributeType::Mixed) and inject your own javascript in the fields `getFieldHtml()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a custom fieldtype, you could just connect two standard dropdown menus with some custom JavaScript. The easiest way to do that would probably be via the [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin.

Fortunately, the control panel already uses jQuery, so you wouldn't need much JS to tie the two fields together.